# How can I set up AWS Route 53 as a DNS for Azure Cloud Service?

Tags: azure, amazon-web-services, dns, cname

I have an Azure Cloud service that is running. I have registered my domain name with Route 53 and I am trying to use Route 53 to set up the DNS. I can't find any simple and clear explanation of how to do this.

My needs are pretty simple. I just want www.abc.com and also abc.com to point to

http://abc.cloudapp.net/

So far I have:

```
Name          Type  Value

abc.com       NS    ns-xxx.net
                    ns-yyy.net
abc.com       SOA   ns-zzz.net
www.abc.com   CNAME abc.cloudapp.net
```

How can I make the abc.com also point to abc.cloudapp.net ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strictly speaking, you don't need a cName in this case.

You can use  records to map abc.com and www.abc.com to the IP address.

Typically I would use a CNAME like this though:

```
abc.com       A     101.101.101.150
www.abc.com   CNAME     abc.com
```

Small, and as far as I can tell only, benefit is that if the IP address ends up changing, I only need to update one record - the 'abc.com'; the 'www.abc.com' won't need to be touched.

Comment: I'm reading that I cannot use a fixed IP address for Azure. I need to map to abc.cloudapp.net  So unfortunately it's back to needing to use a CNAME. Can you suggest how I could do it with a CNAME so it would work for abc.com or www.abc.com?

Comment: I have a route53 domain pointing to an azure vm public IP no problem, so you can definitely do it. Have you tried? I suspect you can't or shouldn't point to a private IP, but if you assign/have a public ip it should work fine.

Comment: @e-j-brennanJ - Thanks for the quick reply.  Yes I tried it and it worked but then started to read that it was not a good idea in case the IP changed.  Now I am not sure what to do. Your suggestion looks like a simple one and it works but then I'm a bit concerned if the IP changes. BTW if I was to go with pointing to abc.clouudapp.net is there a way I could easily do that with different recordsets?

Comment: I just tried and it gives me a message: RRset of type CNAME with DNS name abc.com is not permitted at apex in zone abc.com